# xpath - how to select html element then another (relative) nested element?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, parent-child

How can I select the div element `"fc-event-time` and then, relative to that, the "next" div element that is nested by the same amount?

So, based on the `1p - 2p` text identified this area of HTML, I then want to get at the users names.

Given the following html:

```
<div class="fc-event-inner fc-event-skin">
  <div class="fc-event-head fc-event-skin">
    <div class="fc-event-time" style="background-color: rgb(120, 182, 229);">
      1p - 2p
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="fc-event-title">
      Juan A.*, Zach A.*
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-event-bg">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying the following selector:

```
//div[@class='fc-event-time'][contains(text(),'1p - 2p')]../../div[2]/div
```

but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a forward slash:

```
//div[@class='fc-event-time'][contains(text(),'1p - 2p')]../../div[2]/div
# should be
//div[@class='fc-event-time'][contains(text(),'1p - 2p')]/../../div[2]/div
#                                                        ^ here
```

You may find the tool here (XPathBuilder) helpful:
http://www.bubasoft.net/product/xpath-builder

Comment: Seems like that link is now dead...